# How to replicate statistical significance in STEPAR method of SAS PROC FORECAST?

Tags: autoregressive, sas

This is basically a trend model + Autoregressive Error model

Figuring out the coefficients for the AR model is just a straightforward application of Yule-Walker equations. However, not sure about how they evaluate statistical significance of these coefficients. Anyone have an idea of how to calculate the p-values for these estimated coefficients?

Comment: Can you tell us some more details  of your model and assumptions. Does SAS documentatin say something about methods?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Unfortunately [SAS documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_forecast_sect023.htm) doesn't say anything about how the coefficient significance tests are done (no assumptions on distribution of test statistic).

Comment: It's a 2-stage model, first linear trend against time is estimated through regular OLS. Residuals are then calculated and these are applied to a AR model where a backwards stepwise algorithm is used to select the most significant subset of lags

Comment: Please include extra information as an edit to the post. Not everybody reads comments ...